# Why are my Upper & Lower CI Intervals returning as NA?

Tags: r

```
N <- c(10,100,1000,10000)  
mu1 <- 16/2145
sigma1 <- 6.653*10^-3
CI_UPPER_TRUE <- numeric(5); CI_LOWER_TRUE <- numeric(5);
CI_UPPER_EMP <- numeric(5); CI_LOWER_EMP <- numeric(5);
# 95% Confidence Interval for MC Estimate Of I
for(i in 1:4){
sample <- runif(N[i]) ;
MCE = mean(sample); estvar=sd(sample) ; 
CI_UPPER_TRUE <- mu1 + 1.96*sigma1/sqrt(N[i]);
CI_LOWER_TRUE <- mu1 - 1.96*sigma1/sqrt(N[i]);
CI_UPPER_EMP <- MCE+1.96*estvar/sqrt(N[i]);  #part a iii)
CI_LOWER_EMP <- MCE-1.96*estvar/sqrt(N[i]);  #part a iii)
print(paste(c("The theoretical value of the intergral is",mu1,
              ".The MC estimate of the integral when N=",N[i],
              "is",MCE,".The approximate 95% CI for the MC estimator is ( ",
             CI_LOWER_EMP[i],",",CI_UPPER_EMP[i], "). ")
            ,collapse=" "))
}
```

I'm creating a true confidence interval and approximate confidence interval using the above code. Why is my `CI_LOWER_EMP[i]` & `CI_UPPER_EMP[i]` returning as `NA`?

Answer (score 1):

You had a minor syntax error in accessing the CIs (i.e. `CI_LOWER_EMP[i]` and `CI_UPPER_EMP[i]` should instead simply be `CI_LOWER_EMP` and `CI_UPPER_EMP`)

This works:

```
N <- c(10,100,1000,10000)  
mu1 <- 16/2145
sigma1 <- 6.653*10^-3
CI_UPPER_TRUE <- numeric(5); CI_LOWER_TRUE <- numeric(5);
CI_UPPER_EMP <- numeric(5); CI_LOWER_EMP <- numeric(5);
# 95% Confidence Interval for MC Estimate Of I
for(i in 1:4){
sample <- runif(N[i]) ;
MCE = mean(sample); estvar=sd(sample) ; 
CI_UPPER_TRUE <- mu1 + 1.96*sigma1/sqrt(N[i]);
CI_LOWER_TRUE <- mu1 - 1.96*sigma1/sqrt(N[i]);
CI_UPPER_EMP <- MCE+1.96*estvar/sqrt(N[i]);  #part a iii)
CI_LOWER_EMP <- MCE-1.96*estvar/sqrt(N[i]);  #part a iii)
print(paste(c("The theoretical value of the intergral is",mu1,
              ".The MC estimate of the integral when N=",N[i],
              "is",MCE,".The approximate 95% CI for the MC estimator is ( ",
             CI_LOWER_EMP,",",CI_UPPER_EMP, "). ")
            ,collapse=" "))
}
[1] "The theoretical value of the intergral is 0.00745920745920746 .The MC estimate of the integral when N= 10 is 0.474612841545604 .The approximate 95% CI for the MC estimator is (  0.304842287344748 , 0.64438339574646 ). "
[1] "The theoretical value of the intergral is 0.00745920745920746 .The MC estimate of the integral when N= 100 is 0.513472140908707 .The approximate 95% CI for the MC estimator is (  0.45434775796753 , 0.572596523849884 ). "
[1] "The theoretical value of the intergral is 0.00745920745920746 .The MC estimate of the integral when N= 1000 is 0.492283094468992 .The approximate 95% CI for the MC estimator is (  0.474656355810083 , 0.509909833127901 ). "
[1] "The theoretical value of the intergral is 0.00745920745920746 .The MC estimate of the integral when N= 10000 is 0.501687437707512 .The approximate 95% CI for the MC estimator is (  0.49601943668518 , 0.507355438729844 ). "
```